# How to validate value of K with PSO

Tags: matlab

I am creating bag of visual words using bagOfFeatures() function for my dataset. Here I wanted to know for how many number of clusters do I get a good accuracy value., so I kept changing the values of k from 50 to 400 in steps of 50. like {50,100,150,200,250 ..... 400}. and i get a good accuracy at k=250. This k value I want to validate it with other methods like:

1. automatic identification method of k value for the dataset used. Which is the best method for this.? and also
2. by Using Particle Swarm optimization (PSO).

How i can proceed further. Your inputs are more important to me.

Comment: please show the code for what you have tried

Comment: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52857-particle-swarm-optimization-pso.     This is the link I am referring. But not able to come up how to write the objective function and other parameters to my problem, in identifying k value.